# PHP, проверка входящих данных

Tags: php, mysql, xss, sql-injection

1. На сайте все данные, которые передаются через POST и GET состоят из русских и английских букв, цифр и символов тире, нижнее подчеркивание, точка, собака. Для защиты от MySQL inject, XSS, и прочих атак, будет ли достаточно в начале скрипта отфильтровать массивы $_POST и $_GET регуляркой?

```html
preg_replace("/[^А-Яа-яA-Za-z0-9-_.@]/u", '', $str);
```

2. Правильно ли составлена регулярка?

Answer (score 0):

Такие универсальные решения -- лучше чем ничего.
Но опираться я бы на них не стал.
Даже из этих символов можно кое-что скомбинировать.

От конкретно sql-injection защищают prepared statements.
Не склеивайте ничего в запрос. Бинд-ите.

Если встречается странный символ, я бы предпочел не вырезать его молча,
а явно бросать ошибку с сообщением о причине.
А то через пол года будете отлаживаться пол дня и гадать, почему всё так странно работает.

Answer (score -1):

Вот мой вариант:

```
class security {

    private function clearArray($array) {

        if(is_array($array)) {
            foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
                if(is_array($array[$key])) {
                    security::clearArray($array[$key]);
                } else {
                    $array[$key] = htmlspecialchars($value, ENT_QUOTES);
                }
            }
            return $array;
        } else {
            return false;
        }

    }

    public function clearInput($array) {
        return security::clearArray($array);
    }
}

$obj = new security;

$get = $obj->clearInput($_GET);
$post = $obj->clearInput($_POST);
```

Еще можно экранировать строку так...

```
$get = array_map(array($mysqli, 'real_escape_string'), $_GET);
$post = array_map(array($mysqli, 'real_escape_string'), $_POST);
```

...но здесь требуется идентификатор соединения, т.е...

```
$mysqli = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_UNAME, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);
```

Или если хочешь экранировать конкретную строку, то как вариант...

```
$firstname = $mysqli -> real_escape_string($_POST['firstname']);
```